# Running golang comand in heroku bash

Tags: heroku, go, heroku-toolbelt

Can I use go command in one-off dyno?
The bash responds me:

```
bash: go: command not found
```

I noticed ruby and python are installed, but not go.
There is a way to get go in my slug?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, even with the buildpack. Any solution yet?

Comment: @BastienBeurier I didn't found a solution, but I found a workaround to solve my initial problem. Basically I needed to create my own buildpack. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/compile

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind putting a little more detail on how you used your own buildpack to solve your problem? Is your custom buildpack publicly accessible?

Comment: @BastienBeurier I'm very new to the Heroku development, but the documentation is great, easy to follow: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your original error is because you created the application with heroku create. You're using Go, which is supported through a buildpack, so you should create the application with something like heroku create -b.

Comment: You mean adding go buildpack on "create"? like this: `heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/go`. That didn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

i just had this problem and i'm already using a Go buildpack. i imagine there's a better solution but worth mentioning, found i can directly call whatever the binary from my build is call, at least this worked in my Procfile to start a worker. so maybe finding a way to wrap your calls or dispatching behavior from some "main" method can be a workaround.